# HttpClient GetAsync with query string

Tags: c#, httpclient, google-geocoding-api, getasync

I am using Google's GeoCoding API. I have two methods where one works and the other doesn't and I can't seem to figure out why:

```
string address = "1400,Copenhagen,DK";
string GoogleMapsAPIurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&key={1}";
string GoogleMapsAPIkey = "MYSECRETAPIKEY";
string requestUri = string.Format(GoogleMapsAPIurl, address.Trim(), GoogleMapsAPIkey);

// Works fine                
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri))
    {
        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}

// Doesn't work
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/", UriKind.Absolute);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", GoogleMapsAPIkey);

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("geocode/json?address=1400,Copenhagen,DK"))
    {
        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

My last method with `GetAsync` where I am sending a query string doesn't work and I am in doubt why it is so. When I introduce `BaseAddress` on the client the `GetAsync` somehow doesn't send to the correct URL.

Comment: Note: `using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())` - [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples) is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use.

Comment: This is just a demo console app to show that I can't use a BaseAddress as I want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ciao, the problem is related with `key` parameter on URL. Change your code like this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/");
   
   using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("geocode/json?address=1400,Copenhagen,DK&key=" + GoogleMapsAPIkey))
    {
       var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

As [google sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) said:

> After you have an API key, your application can append the query parameter key=yourAPIKey to all request URLs. The API key is safe for embedding in URLs; it doesn't need any encoding.

Comment: I have tried that: client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/"); and calling GetSync with client.GetAsync("json?address=1400,Copenhagen,DK")) but it returns 403

Comment: And what if client.GetAsync("json?address=1400,Copenhagen,DK&key=MYSECRETAPIKEY")) ?

Comment: I was just about to post that. This seems to work:  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/"); client.GetAsync("json?address=1400,Copenhagen,DK&key=myGoogleAPIkey")

so as long as I am not setting the HTTP Header "key" then it does work. The key apparently needs to be sent as a query parameter. I thought that a HTTP header was standard way to send API keys.

Comment: I Update my answer. Good to ear that!

Comment: Strange that Google doesn't have the option to send the API key as a HTTP Header. Wouldn't it be more secure?

Comment: Yeah I tought the same. But reading [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) they said "After you have an API key, your application can append the query parameter key=yourAPIKey to all request URLs.
The API key is safe for embedding in URLs; it doesn't need any encoding." If google said is secure, must be secure :)

Comment: Checked twice. `UriKind.Absolute` has no effect int this exact case.

Comment: Ok, so the problem was just the key on url. Let me update the answer.

Comment: @OliverNilsen there's no difference on security where API key is located: in URL or in headers. HTTPS is enough to secure it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't suggest adding API key into globals. Maybe you'll need to send some HTTP request outside of the API and the key will be leaked.

Here's the example that works.

```csharp
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

```csharp
public class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private const string GoogleMapsAPIkey = "MYSECRETAPIKEY";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/");

        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            query.Add("address", "1400,Copenhagen,DK");
            dynamic response = await GetAPIResponseAsync<dynamic>("geocode/json", query);
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task<string> ParamsToStringAsync(Dictionary<string, string> urlParams)
    {
        using (HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(urlParams))
            return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    private static async Task<T> GetAPIResponseAsync<T>(string path, Dictionary<string, string> urlParams)
    {
        urlParams.Add("key", GoogleMapsAPIkey);
        string query = await ParamsToStringAsync(urlParams);
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path + "?" + query, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I have this shorter form working fine now. The whole issue was passing the API key as a HTTP header, which Google's geocoding API doesn't accept. You have to send it as part of the query string. So this works for me:

`client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/");  
string requestURI = string.Format("json?address={0}&key={1}", address.Trim(), APIkey);`

Comment: @OliverNilsen You're welcome. Sure, that's shorter but my solution supports any collection of URL parameters not `address` only. It's scalable. I'm not sure that you'll use only `geocode/json` from that API. Then, `string.Format` here produce not proper URL-encoded string, it may fail with some not latin or special characters included. For example, you'll may easily break it with adding `&` or `=` to the `address` value. Just a warning but you may test and compare the resulting urls. Shorter not means better.

Comment: Hmm you might be right if I end up having & or = in the address. Can't I still use string.Format and just use one of the URI encoding methods and encode the address variable?

Comment: @OliverNilsen there's no so many bulletproof methods to encode the string into URL format correctly. One of them shown above, other one available with `HttpUtility` form `System.Web` namespace. But some developers don't like to include that namespace, I don't know why, thus I've shown the common one above. I have no idea why do you prefer to avoid the `ParamsToStringAsync` method approach. Btw, I'ts up to you.